# How can I use insert mode completion in a macro?

Tags: autocompletion, macro

I'm trying to define a macro which quickly generates a list of random-ish words.
I want the macro to turn this into a list like

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

into this

```
arezzo
bywords
czars
détente
eyrie
```

What I have so far:

- put cursor on letter `a`
- start recording macro `qq`
- `a` enter insert mode
- `<C-x><C-k> - perform dictionary completion on the character before cursor - in this case the letter`a`
- `<C-p>` select the last item in the completion list that appears, on my system its the word `arezzo`. (N.B. I have `longest` included in my `'completeopt'` setting, which is required for `<C-p>` to work in this way during completion: `'set completeopt=longest,menuone,preview'`).
- `<C-y>` accept the completion
- `^[^[` exit insert mode
- `j` move down to the next line, ready to do the same operation on the next line
- `q` stop recording

when I create the macro and go through the steps manually, everything works fine, however when I execute the macro, I see a message flashing in the command line something like:

> scanning dictionary file

and nothing happens, of the commands in the macro only `j` is run, i.e. the cursor moves down the line, but none of the completion commands run.
Is it possible to use insert mode completions in a macro, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: I do not understand your `<C-p>` step... when I do that in my vim, it just gives the message `back at original` - doesn't select the last item.. I used up arrow key twice to select last word (my case `azures`), pressed enter and then `Esc+j+q` .. it then works quite fine on executing macro

Comment: @spasic ah good point, I should have mentioned, but I'm using  `set completeopt=longest,menuone,preview` its the `longest` option which causes `<C-p>` to immediately insert. If I remove `longest` from the `completeopt` string, I get the same behaviour as you. Also, yes the arrow keys worked ! thanks
(I forgot you can use them to navigate the completion list)

Comment: Maybe the popup-menu is interfering. Perhaps try `:set completeopt=` and `a<c-x><c-k><esc>j` as your macro.

Comment: @Antony I'm not sure why the <C-p> wasn't working, but the directional arrow keys worked.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Really you are after dictionary completion; you don't necessarily need insert mode (Ctrl + X mode) to do this. As you discovered, it makes working with macros a real pain. The below script can be used to do the dictionary completion without insert mode, so that you can easily repeat it inside of a macro.

Add the below code to your `.vimrc` file, close and reopen any vim windows to source the new function, and then record yourself alternately pressing `<C-k>` to do the completion and `j` to move down to the next line. I added a check for the `longest` option and if it is disabled, it picks a random entry using system random time. If it finds the `longest` option, it manually searches for the longest matching entry from the dictionary, and inserts that.

If you don't like the `<C-k>` mapping, feel free to change it as you see fit. It should work with any mapping you like.

Also, the command to return the expression for the mapping to evaluate adds an `\<esc>` character to the end so that we leave insert mode automatically after each insertion, and an `0cw` at the front to enter insert mode to begin with and make sure we overwrite the entire word correctly. Depending on the exact behavior you want (if your words aren't nicely at the front of each line) you could use `bcw` instead to find the actual word start. However, then you will see some oddities when going back to words that do begin the line. There's probably a more advanced command to ignore the line ending and do both at once, but I couldn't find one.

```
map <expr> <C-k> CompleteDictionary()
fun! CompleteDictionary()
    let cword = expand(“<cword>”)
    let res = []
    for m in readfile(&dictionary)
        if m =~ '^' . cword
            call add(res, m)
        endif
    endfor
    if &completeopt =~ 'longest'
        let max = 0
        let maxindex = 0
        let index = 0
        for item in res
            if strlen(item) > max
                let max = strlen(item)
                let maxindex = index
            endif
            let index = index + 1
        endfor
        return "0cw" . res[maxindex] . "\<esc>"
    else
        return "0cw" . res[system('@echo %RANDOM%') % len(res)] . "\<esc>"
    endif
endfun
```

In addition, it would not be difficult to extend the logic here to create alternate mappings (using, for example, function parameters) that perform any function the insert mode provides. I'll be happy to assist with any such requirements and update this script as I have time.

Comment: This sounds like a plausible explanation of the issue, but I tried both your suggested solutions, and neither seemed to help.

Comment: Did you try the `sleep` command as well?

Comment: Yes, although only with your suggested value of 5 seconds. Have you managed to get either solution to work? Could you post a complete list of steps?

Comment: I am not the person who wrote the question. However, I *can* reproduce the issue: you have to add *longest* to `completeopt` as described in the comments (again, not by me). **edit**: Oops, `'longest'` is required for the `ctrl-p` step: not `ctrl-y`. Still the steps described by the question-asker work for me in `vim -Nu NONE` with `completeopt` edited.

Comment: I think I've found a solution, give me a few minutes to update my answer with it.

Comment: Nice solution! Unfortunately (for me) it's one that skirts around the part of the question I was interested in: I never use dictionary completion! But writing this it occurs to me that, while I had a vague feeling that I'd experienced similar issues with other completion flavours in the past, I'm now not at all certain that that is actually the case. And I definitely don't have an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: @Rich Interesting, which flavor do you use? I looked at the others while researching this, and none looked absolutely impossible to reproduce through other means. In general though, I’ve found that there are certain things Vim just won’t do, and it’s usually better to find an alternative route than to beat Vim over the head with something it seems to dislike doing. One of those things appears to be, managing multiple layers of modes while recording macros.